# how to rollback after git pull

Tags: git, macos, github

Problem is I've push my code into github before my mac's LED displayed got wrong.
That's why I've hired my friend mac and develop some codes into it but I've forgot to push some changes code into github. When my mac is recovered, I just copy and paste into my mac. At that time, I'm trying to push those changes into github and got error that I need to `git pull` first. Once `git pull` is done, all of my new changes are gone. Please help me how to recover my changes code?

Answer (score 1):

you could:

`$ git reflog`

to see all tips of branches and other references that were updated in your local repository.

Then, once you find the branch or point where you did your `$git pull`, you can reset the current branch to the point before that `$git pull` took place (however, *a warning here*, you need to be absolutely sure before resetting with the **`--hard`** option)

So, suppose that the old commit was HEAD@{3} in the ref log, you would do:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD@{3}
```

When you do succeed to recover your changes, I recommend creating a branch off of them. Then you get your local master to sync with remote (`$git pull`), and then merge your branch with your local master (no fast forward `--no-ff`), and deal with any emerge conflicts, before doing a final `$git push`

hope that helps.